# JavaScript loop with <tr>

Tags: javascript, html

I´m trying to make a calender for a school assignment using JavaScript, in my Function Kalander loop i tried to generate the days of the month inside  and . I'm not quite sure how i fit in the openening  inside the loop. i'd like to have rows of 7 days.

HMTL:

```
html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<center>
<button id="Vorige" onclick="VorigeFunc()">Vorige</button> <button id="Volgende" onclick="VolgendeFunc()">Volgende</button>
<br>
<table id="cal">
</table>
<div id="div">
<script type="text/javascript" src="Kal.js"> </script>
</div>
</center>
</body>

</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var monthLength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var today = new Date();
var dag = today.getDay();
var myMonth = today.getMonth();
var jaar = today.getFullYear();

var VolgendeFunc = function(){
    myMonth = myMonth + 1;
    Kalender();
}

var VorigeFunc = function(){
    myMonth = myMonth -1;
    Kalender();
}

function Kalender(){
    var myHTML ='';
    myHTML+=monthNames[myMonth] + " " + jaar + "<br>";
    for (var i=1; i <= monthLength[myMonth]; i++)
    {
        myHTML+="<td><a href='#'>" + i + "</a></<td> ";
        if (i%7 == 0) { myHTML += "</tr>"; } 
    } 

    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = myHTML;
}
window.onload=Kalender();
```

Comment: How specifically does this fail?  When you step through this in a debugger, where does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?  Is the `myHTML` string being created the way you expect?  Is it being set to the `div`?  How exactly does this not work?

Comment: `window.onload=Kalender();` should be `window.onload=Kalender;` but since it is after the elmenets, there is no need for the window.onload, it can just be `Kalender();`

Comment: the problem is that the <tr> at the start of each row isnt included, i'm not sure where i include that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve your problem you need to select the right container. I've removed your table from the markup and added it dynamically with your JS.

I've placed the month in another container not to interfere with the table. You could optionally place the month inside a thead tag.

I threw you a bonus and added button functionality and restricted behaviour for 2014 (take this and improve it to a unrestricted year calendar). Make it your exercise.

See the [JsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nw3f2w6o/2)

HTML

```
<button id="Vorige" onclick="VorigeFunc();">Vorige</button>
<button id="Volgende" onclick="VolgendeFunc();">Volgende</button>
<br>
<div id="div">
</div>
```

JS

```
var dayNames = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
var monthNames = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
var monthLength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
var today = new Date();
var dag = today.getDay();
var myMonth = today.getMonth();
var jaar = today.getFullYear();
var volBtn = document.getElementById('Volgende');
var vorBtn = document.getElementById('Vorige');

function Kalender(){
    var myHTML ='';

    myHTML+='<div id="month">'+monthNames[myMonth] + " " + jaar+'</div><table id="cal">';

    for (var i=1; i <= monthLength[myMonth]; i++){
        myHTML+="<td><a href='#'>" + i + "</a></<td> ";

        if (i%7 == 0){
            myHTML += "</tr>";
        } 
    }
     myHTML+='</table>';

    document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = myHTML;
}

var VolgendeFunc = function(){
   myMonth = myMonth + 1;
    if (myMonth == 11){
       volBtn.disabled = true;
       vorBtn.disabled = false;  
    } else {
       vorBtn.disabled = false; 
       volBtn.disabled = false;
    }
   document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = myMonth;
   Kalender();
}

var VorigeFunc = function(){
    myMonth = myMonth - 1;
   if (myMonth == 0){
       vorBtn.disabled = true;
       volBtn.disabled = false; 
   } else {
       vorBtn.disabled = false;
       volBtn.disabled = false; 
    }
    document.getElementById('month').innerHTML = myMonth;
    Kalender();
}

Kalender();
```